# the select statement includes a reserved word or argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect - VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

```
strQuery1 = "SELECT 'Health Start Lite' AS HSL_RAW_ProductName, Max(HSL_RAW.[DateCreated]) AS MaxOfDateCreated," & _
"HSL_RAW.[Premium], Last(HSL_RAW.[FirstName]) AS LastOfFirstName, HSL_RAW.[LastName]," & _
"HSL_RAW.[EmailAddress], HSL_RAW.[MobileNumber], HSL_RAW.[Partner], Last(HSL_RAW.[Stage]) AS LastOfStage" & _
"FROM ...
```

Comment: What VBA line throws the error?  It's not this one, this is just the SQL text that causes the error.  Also what version of ADO, ODBC and SQL Server's are you using?  I suspect it's the `Last(..)` function, which your ODBC/ADO driver may not recognize.  You will probably either need to put your connection into passthru mode or else use a stored procedure instead.

Comment: 'Open the recordset.
    rs.Open strQuery1, con

Comment: OK, it's definitely the `Last(..)` function which I don't think is valid in SQL Server at all.  You might try `TOP (1)` or a subquery/CTE that uses ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: I'll try wait. Thanks :)

Comment: Try replacing it with the `LAST_VALUE(..) ORDER BY (..)` function.

Comment: Still the same error :(

Comment: 'Set the name of the query you want to run and retrieve the data.
    strQuery1 = "SELECT 'Health Start Lite' AS HSL_RAW_ProductName, Max(HSL_RAW.[DateCreated]) AS MaxOfDateCreated," & _
    "HSL_RAW.[Premium], Top(HSL_RAW.[FirstName]) AS LastOfFirstName, HSL_RAW.[LastName]," & _
    "HSL_RAW.[EmailAddress], HSL_RAW.[MobileNumber], HSL_RAW.[Partner], Top(HSL_RAW.[Stage]) AS LastOfStage"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space missing between `LastOfStage` and `FROM`. Should be:

```
 "... AS LastOfStage" & _
 " FROM ..."
```

Note the space before `FROM`.

Comment: WOW I did not notice that! Thank you so much :D